# Why is not created the install_aarch64/share directory? - cross compile tool

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to compile a ROS2 foxy demo in my pc running a VM with Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and then run it in my 64 bits arm processor running Linux Ubuntu 20.04 arm64, I am using this [tool](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile), I install the [prerequisites](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile#prerequisites), when I install docker I use [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) method and then I use [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) steps to run containers as a non-root user as mentioned in the prerequisites part:

Prerequisites

This tool requires that you have already installed

**Docker
Follow the instructions to add yourself to the docker group as well, so you can run containers as a non-root user**

Python 3.6 or higher

then I install the [ross cross compile](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile#installing-ros_cross_compile) and follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile#tutorial), everything goes ok but I realize 2 things:

1.- the [expected outputs](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile#outputs-of-the-build) are not the same
I don´t have the tutorial.repos

2.- the install_aarch64/share path is not created, I realize this when I [try to run the build in my target](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile#using-the-build-on-a-target-platform), in this step:

rosdep install --from-paths install_aarch64/share --ignore-src --rosdistro foxy -y

I got an error that says that the install_aarch64/share directory does not exists and wen I enter In the install_aarch64 directory I can confirm that

what could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389727/why-is-not-created-the-install_aarch64/share-directory?---cross-compile-tool/) by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tool had a bug, now it is fixed

---

Originally posted by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) with karma: 31 on 2021-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
Could you link to where it is fixed? A pull request perhaps?

**Comment by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) on 2021-11-10**:
https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
That's a link to the repository. If the bug was fixed in that repository, could you link to where it was fixed?

**Comment by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) on 2021-11-10**:
I don´t know, I am not the repo owner or mantainer, you could search in the issues tab in the repo

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
You wrote:

> The tool had a bug, now it is fixed

so how did you notice it is now fixed?

You just updated it and it happened to work when you tried again?

**Comment by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) on 2021-11-11**:
I was trying to use it and I could not do it so I open an issue, read the issues

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-11**:
Why not just link us to those issues? I'm not sure I understand what the problem was to do that in your initial answer.

**Comment by [jg_spitfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/88138/jg_spitfire/) on 2021-11-11**:
You could check the issues in the repo, I shared the link before

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-11**:
There seems to be only a single issue opened by you: [ros-tooling/cross_compile#342](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile/issues/342).